# git submodue fatal: unable to fork repo in bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

My bitbucket repository contains submodule pointing to another bitbucket repository. When I try to install submodules with `git submodule update --init` command. Bitbucket pipeline throws git error **fatal: unable to fork repository**. Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [article](https://bitbucket.org/blog/cloning-another-bitbucket-repository-in-bitbucket-pipelines) I was able to solve my problem.

## Step 1

Make sure that you build has installed **git** and **ssh** client. Because, I was using git `docker/compose:1.24.0` image. I had to run this command in my **bitbucket-pipipelines.yaml** file.

```
- apk add git
- apk add openssh-client
```

## Step 2

Create SSH keys for the main repository. In bitbucket got to your repository and then click  `Repository settings > SSH keys > Generate keys`  and click `Copy public key`.

## Step 3

Add SSH public key to the target (submodule) repository. In bitbucket got to your submodule repository and then click `Repository settings > Access keys` and click `Add key` button and add the key obtained in **Step 2**.

Now your pipeline should fetch depending submodule without any problem.

Comment: I was using `image: atlassian/pipelines-awscli` and `apk add openssh-client` helped. Thank you!